# Why are radial engines louder than inline engines?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-performance

After visiting Oshkosh, I've noticed that radial-engine powered aircraft tend to be louder than in-line engine aircraft.

For example, watching a Ford Trimotor take off seems to be louder than most other aircraft I watched.

Comment: I would also wonder if a radial simply directs more noise towards where people tend to be observing and so sound louder even if the engine were not to put out more noise in an absolute sense.

Answer (score 21):

To add to Max's answer:

All radial engines have an odd number of cylinders and the older ones had two-bladed propellers. So for a 7-cylinder radial, two turns of the prop would furnish 4 blade passages and 7 power pops from the exhaust. The blended result- seven beats against four- is not harmonically related and to our ears the result is more harsh and annoying.

Motorcycle engine designers know this and actually play with the crank timing and the vee angle between the cylinders on their V-twin engines to make them sound as rough and unpleasant (i.e., "badass") as possible.

Comment: A certain type of motorcycles I should add. Harleys (US brand, no surprise) in particular.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek, all the japanese manufacturers do this. My Kawasaki vulcan 1500 was designed for the best exhaust sound, then a counterbalance shaft was added to the engine to cancel the out-of-balance vibrations caused by the  crankshaft timing!

Comment: The Japanese manufacturers might do it, but they do it on their V-twin cruisers , which could be thought of as American style bikes.  The don't (routinely at least) do it on their sportier classes.  So @SebastiaanvandenBroek is thinking along the right lines, just considering manufacturers rather than markets

Comment: Though the reason for odd number of cylinders is so that the power strokes are distributed regularly. As a four-stroke engine fires on every second stroke, 7 cylinders allow a regular pattern of 1.3.5.7.2.4.6..

Comment: @JanHudec what’s less regular about 1 3 5 7 2 4 6 8? Or even 1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8? I suspect there’s more to it than regularity?

Answer (score 16):

I suspect you are looking at a whole list of things that contribute to this in varying degrees, not one specific cause:

- Some of the later radial engines were very large displacement engines
- Almost no ability to tune the lengths of the exhaust paths individually to each cylinder
- An era when there was less concern for noise abatement so effort wasn’t made
- The size of the cooling fins and their direct exposure to your ears without having to pass through a cowling
- Advancements in materials science in terms of what the cylinders are made of
- Significant advancements in quality of ignition sparks, valve timing, and fuel chemistry

I actually think that last one may be one of the largest contributors.  Completion of fuel burn before the exhaust valve opens is harder to accomplish in large engines to begin with, and is only made harder by the limited technologies of the radial era.  Noise can often be a function of still having significant fuel burning when the exhaust valve opens.

Answer (score 0):

The mere fact of being air-cooled not water-cooled, might contribute, too.  I've noticed water-cooled motorcycle engines seem to be muffled in their sonic emissions, compared to air-cooled ones.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).